# Git Repository Inside of a Tortoise SVN Repository

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

One of my customers has some folders on his server which are synchronized with a Tortoise SVN server. I work in a subfolder of one of these folders and would like to set up a local Git repository there to better track my local changes. Are there any problems to be expected with this constellation? What do I have to pay attention to when setting up and using the Git repository?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Just make sure to ignore git-related files in svn, you are good to go, I had a similar project a few years ago. had no problem.
also, check out git-svn
https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-work-with-svn-using-git-34f1d7a5152c
I didn't use it but can be another solution

Comment: I Remember one problem, be careful with this setup, your client can remove your code if they are actively using the svn repo,

Comment: @AliReza Thank you for your comments. Can you maybe clarify your last post a bit?

Comment: If you have `.git` folder inside WC, your repo can be easy deleted by any (local) user

Answer (score 0):

> folder structure organized as a Tortoise SVN repository

It can't exist in nature: TortoiseSVN is SVN-client, it can create repository on local local FS, but this repo will be separate from "folder structure" (Working Copy of repo?) object

You *can* create git-repo in one folder of WC of SVN-repo (and *carefully define rules* for ignoring git-added artifacts in SVN), using this folder as Working directory of gt, but from my POV such "mixed" workspace will bring more headache, than benefits - think about changed files during WIP in one VCS and updating files on checkout|updates (changed for one VCS, visible in both).

Git svn with cloning *only needed subtree from svn repo* seems as more smart and bullet-proof way

Comment: Sorry for the misleading wording, I am not a native speaker. I'll try to formulate it differently again: The customer has several folders that are synchronized with the server via SVN. I work on the client. Since the server is only updated occasionally, the status on the client is decisive for me. And there I want to use Git in a subfolder. Is that possible with Git SVN? My understanding was that Git SVN clones from the SVN server, not from the client.

Comment: @MatterOfFact - more details needed. That is (for you) "client", have you access to WC, why repo updated occasionally, can you initiate setup-modifications? *We can switch to German, I know it as shitty as English, but at least it will be native for you*

Comment: Thank you. Contacted you via LinkedIn. We can then return here once the misunderstandings have been cleared up.